# Exibir mensagem diferente de acordo com o horário

Tags: javascript, data

Preciso de ajuda para fazer aparecer, conforme o horário que abri a pagina mostrar Bom dia, Boa tarde ou boa noite, alguém pode me ajudar?

```
function carregar() {
  var msg = document.getElementById("msg")
  var img = document.getElementById("imagem")
  var data = new Date() //aqui é para mostrar a data atual
  var hora = data.getHours() //aqui é para mostrar a hora atual
  var minuto = data.getMinutes() // aqui vai mostrar os minutos

  msg.innerHTML = 'Agora são ' + hora + " : " + minuto + ' horas.'
  if (hora >= 0 && hora < 12) {
    //Bom dia !
    img.src = "imagens/fotomanha.png"
    document.body.style.background = "#fee389" // aqui vai mudar a cor de fundo conforme o hrario do dia


  } else if (hora >= 12 && hora < 18) {
    //Boa tarde !
    img.src = "imagens/fototarde.png"
    document.body.style.background = "#bc6317" // aqui vai mudar a cor de fundo conforme o hrario do dia

  } else {
    //Boa Noite !
    img.src = "imagens/fotonoite.png"
    document.body.style.background = "#0b191a" // aqui vai mudar a cor de fundo conforme o hrario do dia
  }

}
```

Comment: aparentemente seu código está certo. Você está chamando a função?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sua pergunta foi muito pouco especifica, onde você quer que exiba? No elemento msg? Um alert? Se for na mensagem você pode fazer assim:

```
if (hora >= 0 && hora < 12) {
    msg.innerHTML += ' Bom Dia!'
    img.src = "imagens/fotomanha.png"
    document.body.style.background = "#fee389" 
  } else if (hora >= 12 && hora < 18) {
    msg.innerHTML += ' Boa Tarde!'
    img.src = "imagens/fototarde.png"
    document.body.style.background = "#bc6317" 

  } else {
    msg.innerHTML += ' Boa Noite!'
    img.src = "imagens/fotonoite.png"
    document.body.style.background = "#0b191a" 
  }
```

Com esse '+=' você concatena o valor que já existe no innerHTML mais a mensagem que pode ser de bom dia, boa tarde ou boa noite.

Comment: obrigada, era assim mesmo que eu queria.

Comment: De nada. Não esquece aceitar minha resposta, que isso ajuda bastante.